# Connect Pop OS to TV using Miracast

Tags: wifi, display, screencasting

I have been trying to find a way to connect my Pop!_OS to my TV using Miracast for quite some time. Tried to set up Miracast for straight 2 days but was unable to get it to work. I'm kind of frustrated now. Is there any other way that I can connect my laptop to my TV using Miracast?

Laptop Serial Number: 4HNQP72

```
~$ iwlist frequency

lo        no frequency information.

wlp6s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

enp7s0    no frequency information.
```

Comment: Miracast is supported on my laptop. I have checked.

Comment: Please advise a) which WiFi channel you are using by running `nm-tool && iwlist frequency`, b) the model of your TV, and c) the model number of your laptop from the serial number sticker beneath, so we can see if your WiFi adapter in the laptop one of the two supported (Intel 7260-family or Atheros ath9k) https://github.com/intel/wds/blob/master/README.md . Please click [edit] to add that info to your question. Please do not use Add Comment; click [edit] to add the results to your question instead.

Comment: @K7AAY I have added the serial number and the result of iwlist frequency but the nm-tool is not working.

Comment: Sorry, old advice used. Use `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Frequency | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` instead. Also need the _model_ number off the serial number plate as asked above.  Instead of Please click [edit] to add that info to your question. Please do not use Add Comment; click [edit] to add the results to your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Miracast has been [criticized for incomplete implementation](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ag8jfd/connecting_to_smart_tvs_intelmiracast_streaming/) in the Pop! OS forum at Reddit. The one implementation which worked was [Miraclecast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) which is a non-trivial task to configure, but you can also review [Wireless Display Software for Linux](https://01.org/wds).